# Agora Video Resolution In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm working on an app that uses agora sdk for unity. I'm rendering video on UI Raw Images and using a video resolution of 480x480. The thing is that the video in those images looked a bit stretched and to handle that I set the orientation to fixed portrait and it looks better but not perfect. So I want to ask, do I need to resize the images according to video resolution i.e. if video resolution is of 480x480 then the raw image size should be 480x480 in width and height as well? I also need to present a user's video in a much larger image so what video resolution should I choose given the size of raw image 980(w) x 1600(h). I just need the videos to best fit the images so it looks good. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should resize the image according the resolution in general.  There is a callback method that tells what the video resolution size is. You may find that information in VideoSurface's code where reference to UpdateVideoRawData() is.  The actual Raw Image itself doesn't have to match the size and the data will fill in within boundary.  You should maintain a width/height ratio.  Or if you want to crop the image, you may need to apply some masking technique.  Crop the video data itself maybe another approach but that will add CPU overhead for you.

Comment: What do you mean by width/height ration? I've seen video profiles for Unity and in the recommended profiles, max resolution is 1280x720. So what if I want to display 1080p quality video. Thanks.

Comment: The current Agora Unity SDK and regular native SDK does not support 1080p.
I was talking about aspect ratio, like 16:9, 5:4, etc. So a rawimage to host a 1280x720 image could be 400x225 or 711x400 if you don't want o crop it.

Comment: Oh thank-you so much! so as long as I use resolutions having aspect ratio 16:9, the video won't get stretched or cropped?

Comment: Thankyou so much @Rick :)